# What is the rationale behind UI namespace in Qt?

Tags: qt, user-interface, namespaces

In the process of creating a user interface code from UI file Qt creates 2 classes with just the same definition.

```
class UI_CustomeUIClassFromUIFile
{
//code generated from UI file thru UIC
}
namespace ui
{
class CustomeUIClassFromUIFile public : UI_CustomeUIClassFromUIFile{};
}using namespace ui;
```

What is the reason for having 2 classes with just one inside UI namespace and other without namspace? Is it to support compiler that has no support for namespace, there is also a macro some thing like QTNAMESPACE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro is QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE which is what is used if you compiled Qt to be inside of a [custom namespace](http://www.qtcentre.org/forum/f-qt-programming-2/t-whats-effect-of-qt-begin-namespace-thanks-15946.html).

As for the 2 classes, I think you answered it your self.  You can either use `Ui_XXX` or `Ui::XXX`.  I always prefer the `Ui::` method, but to each their own.

So I guess I don't have a real answer as to the rationale other than letting the programmer choose.

Comment: The only sensible explanation I can come up with is that Ui_XXX might have been the original solution and they kept it so legacy code isn't broken.

Answer (score 1):

qt/trolltech (& now nokia) published a great doclet on API design which talks about best practice for APIs. There might be an explanation for this [there](http://chaos.troll.no/~shausman/api-design/api-design.pdf).